# Why must the lifetime of A be longer than 'a for Box<Fn<A, Output = ()> + 'a>?

Tags: rust

In [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=324f93588d69f97985f7d301f24858ae&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015), why must the lifetime of `A` be longer than `'a` for `Box<Fn<A, Output = ()> + 'a>`?

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

trait Tt {}

struct S<'a, A: Copy + 'a> {
    x: Box<Fn<A, Output = ()> + 'a>,
}

fn add<'a, A: Copy + 'a>(x: Box<Fn<A, Output = ()> + 'a>) -> Box<dyn Tt + 'a> {
    Box::new(S::<'a, A> { x })
}

impl<'a, A: Copy + 'a> Tt for S<'a, A> {}
```

`A` is the argument list of `Fn<A, Output = ()>`. Why isn't the lifetime of `A` the *duration of calling `Fn<A, Output = ()>`* but instead *longer than `Fn<A, Output = ()>`*?

**UPDATE 1**

[If `A` isn't specified any lifetime longer than `'a` explicitly, the compiler will raise a error `` the parameter type `A` may not live long enough ``.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4968d4f9a28685a81c6db25d61b3d180&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

trait Tt {}

struct S<'a, A: Copy> {
    x: Box<Fn<A, Output = ()> + 'a>,
}

fn add<'a, A: Copy>(x: Box<Fn<A, Output = ()> + 'a>) -> Box<dyn Tt + 'a> {
    Box::new(S::<'a, A> { x })
}

impl<'a, A: Copy> Tt for S<'a, A> {}
```

`A` is the argument list of `Fn<A, Output = ()>`, which should be live from the begin to the end of calling `Fn<A, Output = ()>`. **I think the lifetime of `A` shouldn't be affected by the lifetime of `Fn<A, Output = ()>`** . But the compiler requires the lifetime of `A` must be longer than `Fn<A, Output = ()>`, aka `'a`. Why?

Comment: As written, `A` _does_ have lifetime `'a`. What makes you think it "must"? Was there a compiler error on some previous version of this code which led you to that  conclusion?

Comment: @PeterHall If `A` isn't specified lifetime that longer than ``'a`` explicitly, the compiler will raise error ``the parameter type `A` may not live long enough``.